# GeoServer publish raster mbtiles with png8

Tags: raster, geoserver

I had a raster mbtles, the raster was png8 in blob field. When I published the mbtiles, the level 0 (only one picture) was correct,

[image: level0]
but other levels were wrong.
[image: level1]
[image: level3]
It seemed different color palette was loaded. How could I do?

Comment: What version of GeoServer is that?

Comment: GeoServer version is 2.17